# How to like, comment and share any page's post using facebook graph api version 3.0?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I need to like any post of a specific page or comment on any post, also get the acknowledgment of same, I was trying to do it using `{post_id}/likes` but unable to get success with that getting below error.

```
"error": {
"message": "(#3) Publishing likes through the API is only available for page access tokens",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 3,
"fbtrace_id": "HdCi0LOJqpk"}}
```

Comment: And what part of the error message that’s telling you what’s up in plain English don’t you understand …?

Comment: what is your specific use case anyway? why not just let the user like something on facebook.com? why would you need to know if he liked something?

Comment: @CBroe I understand what error message is telling but I want to like a post with user token not with the page token, Can you please suggest me a way to do same.

Comment: @luschn We want to track this events from our app so in return we can provide them creadit points

Comment: That is not even allowed - please go read [Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy) before you proceed. And _because_ so many people were _abusing_ this by rewarding users, it was removed. That it is not possible any more even for legitimate apps, is “thanks” to developers doing sh*t like you are trying here.